# Fit rect() around text() width

Tags: javascript, canvas, text, p5.js, rect

I am using p5.js for something and I need to have text inside rectangles appearing at the top of my canvas. I want this text to force the rect() around it to fit so that there is no empty space of the rectangle, it just wraps around the string.
Previously I tried giving the rectangle dimensions manually, though this worked poorly depending on the length of the string. I have looked at using HTML5's canvas 'measureText' and 'fillText' functions, though these work only for the html canvas, not the javascript canvas I have loaded a background image onto.

I want to have the coloured rectangle fit around the text, on the JS canvas as below.
[JS background image canvas with rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIiGi.png)

With the following code:

```
function word (x) {
this.wordX = x;
this.wordY = random(5,30);

this.display = function(){
    fill('#4545f5');
    rect(this.wordX,this.wordY,420,55);
    fill('#ffffff');
    textSize(25);
    text("alphabet", this.wordX+5, this.wordY+10, 410, 55); 
}
```

What can I use to make the box fit neatly around the text and still use the JS background canvas, or can I put an image from a file onto the HTML canvas?
Following is the setup() code for instantiation and canvas drawing:

```
function preload() { 
    BG = loadImage('images/background.PNG'); 
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth,windowHeight);
    word1 = new word(random(10,windowWidth-370));
}

function draw() {
  image(BG, 0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

  word1.display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrates using `measureText()` on a canvas context created with `createCanvas()`

```
const element = createCanvas(300, 400);
const context = element.getContext('2d');

context.font = `22px sans-serif`;
console.log(context.measureText('hello world').width);

context.font = `22px cursive`;
console.log(context.measureText('hello world').width);
```

Comment: Where should code similar to that go? Wherever I put it. it gives me an error: 'element.getContext is not a function', or 'element is not defined' (across two functions) etc. Should this go in the word.js function altogether somewhere, even though it's defining the canvas?

Comment: If your `setup()` works fine, then I put it there as a test to see if it works.